# Typed racket require module repeated evaluation

Tags: syntax, macros, racket, typed

This is a follow-on to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65410792/3414663) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65409389/3414663).

When this code is saved to a file and run from the command line, it prints 13 three times. Twice I can understand, but three times? Why?

When I run it from racket-mode in emacs it prints 13 five times!

And when I run it in DrRacket it prints 13 seven times!

The behaviour is also different in vanilla Racket? Changing `#lang typed/racket` to `#lang racket` prints 13 once from the command line, twice from emacs and three times from DrRacket.

What's going on here?

```lisp
#lang typed/racket

(module for-syntax-mod typed/racket
  (provide foo)
  (: foo (-> Real Real))
  (define (foo n)
    (+ n 3)))

(require (for-syntax 'for-syntax-mod))

(begin-for-syntax (println (foo 10)))
```

Comment: This essentially is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63001494/why-does-require-for-syntax-m-execute-expressions-in-the-required-module-3

Comment: Wow, a link where both rfindler and samth say they're not sure what's going on! I've a feeling we're not in Kansas any more.